Toilet cap replacement
My fix it guy repaired my leaking toilet but didn’t tighten down the bolts so the caps can go back on. Now that I have silicone the toilet at the floor and didn’t check the caps before doing so i feel that is a problem.
What can I do to resolve this issue without having to cut silicone?
Thanks

These are the bolts that hold the toilet to the floor?  Are they tight enough to stop the toilet rocking/moving?

Yes but the bolt is too tall, I can’t put cap back on

Brand new toilet bolts usually come extra long, so that they fit thicker toilet bases as necessary.  You're supposed to trim off the excess if you have caps that need to fit over them.  Many bolts even come with notches to help you position your hacksaw.  Example below, you would saw the part of the threads that are notched (or you could even just use vise grips to break that short section off).

